# Why @Contexthierarchy doesn't caching beans if set @Enableconfigurationproperties?

Tags: java, spring

I decided to write a "component" test without "@SpringBootTest". @Сontexthierarchy doesn't caching beans if set @Enableconfigurationproperties.

When I run "TestOne" and "TestTwo" together, the HelloWorld component is initialized twice, as evidenced by the double appearance of the string in "init666". What could be the problem?

**TestOne**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestOneConfiguration.class)
})
public class TestOne {

    @Autowired
    HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Test
    public void test () {

    }

}
```

**TestOneConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class TestOneConfiguration {
}
```

**TestTwo**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestTwoConfiguration.class)
})
public class TestTwo {

    @Autowired
    HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Test
    public void test () {

    }
}
```

**TestTwoConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class TestTwoConfiguration {
}
```

**TestConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    HelloWorld helloWorld () {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
```

**HelloWorld**

```
@Component

    public class HelloWorld {
        public HelloWorld() {
            System.out.println("init666");
        }
    }
```

**Screenshot**: [double appearance of the string in "init666"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbtGH.jpg)

P.S. @SpringBootTest can not be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I found the only solution:

Get rid of @Enableconfigurationproperties

Load properties from application.yml

**TestOne**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class,
                       initializers = TestContextInitializer.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestOneConfiguration.class)
})

public class TestOne {

    @Autowired
    HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Test
    public void test () {

    }
}
```

**TestContextInitializer**

```
public class TestContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        try {
            Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:application.yml");
            YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
            PropertySource<?> yamlTestProperties = sourceLoader.load("applicationProperties", resource, null);
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(yamlTestProperties);
            String[] profiles = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.profiles.active").replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(profiles);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Engrave the required fields through Enviroment

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment; 

public Someclass somemethod() {
    Someclass someclass = new Someclass();
    String someField = environment.getProperty("someField");
    someclass.setSomeField(someField);
    return someclass;
}
```

If there is, something better I'll be glad to see the proposals.
Thanks!